# A word to describe taking pleasure in the way a word sounds

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that describes one's satisfaction in the phonetics of a word?
Like visual appeal of a pictures, but the audible appeal of a word.

Comment: Are you asking for a word describing the *pleasure* or the *sound*? If it's the sound, you can say it's *mellifluous*.

Comment: Another word for audible appeal is euphony, though I admit that "mellifluous" is more euphonic than "euphony".

Comment: Hamlet:
    Speak the speech, I pray you, as I pronounc'd it to you,
    trippingly on the tongue; but if you mouth it, as many of our
    players do, I had as lief the town-crier spoke my lines.
    Hamlet Act 3, scene 2, 1–4

Answer (score 2):

The go-to word for this quality is ***[euphony](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/euphony)***:

> Good phonetic quality of certain words.

More poetic options include [mellifluousness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mellifluousness) and [consonance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consonance)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is entirely germane to your question - whether you're talking about the phonetics as it leaves your mouth or as it hits your ear - but I'll offer "mouthfeel" for the "as it leaves your mouth" part. It is typically used of foods to talk about how it feels in your mouth. (Think of pudding versus crackers versus steak.)

I've never been entirely sure it was appropriate to apply "mouthfeel" to words as well, but I'm not aware of anything else.

Personally, I have loved the "mouthfeel" of the name "Sam" since I was a small child.

Comment: "mouthfeel" just sounds really weird, to me.

Comment: I don't disagree @MaxWilliams :)